# How can I unapply a subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, workflow

I accidentally applied a subdivision surface modifier, but I don't want that. I tried to undo it, but that is not working. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can discover the global history. If you can find the operat，then you can back to there by click.

following the link：
http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/undo_and_redo.html?highlight=history